# Delete unselected min max time from each different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to optimized my table from unnecessary all employee time data on each single day. So I've to remove unselected necessary time all of employee from each day. But here I try to figure the table but when I running my query with minim id employee, the query work properly. But when I try into the original table that have many employee id, at least 60, but the result is selecting every min max time from each employee id and removing from all other days. And try my query and also search from StackOverflow post about it.

This my table:

| IDkaryawan | authDateTime | tanggal | jam | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-26 17:07:52 | 2023-05-26 | 17:07:52 | Clock Out |
| 1 | 2023-05-29 07:44:54 | 2023-05-29 | 07:44:54 | Clock In |
| 1 | 2023-05-29 17:05:56 | 2023-05-29 | 17:05:56 | Clock Out |
| 1 | 2023-05-30 07:45:37 | 2023-05-30 | 07:45:37 | Clock In |
| 1 | 2023-05-30 17:04:57 | 2023-05-30 | 17:04:57 | Clock Out |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 07:38:44 | 2023-05-31 | 07:38:44 | Clock In |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 17:08:26 | 2023-05-31 | 17:08:26 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-26 17:01:58 | 2023-05-26 | 17:01:58 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-29 17:01:03 | 2023-05-29 | 17:01:03 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-29 07:51:36 | 2023-05-29 | 07:51:36 | Clock In |
| 10 | 2023-05-30 07:53:48 | 2023-05-30 | 07:53:48 | Clock In |
| 10 | 2023-05-30 17:01:59 | 2023-05-30 | 17:01:59 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-30 17:02:05 | 2023-05-30 | 17:02:05 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-31 07:56:05 | 2023-05-31 | 07:56:05 | Clock In |
| 10 | 2023-05-31 17:00:20 | 2023-05-31 | 17:00:20 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-26 18:00:35 | 2023-05-26 | 18:00:35 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-26 18:00:39 | 2023-05-26 | 18:00:39 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-29 07:24:41 | 2023-05-29 | 07:24:41 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-29 07:24:45 | 2023-05-29 | 07:24:45 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-29 17:30:24 | 2023-05-29 | 17:30:24 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-29 17:30:20 | 2023-05-29 | 17:30:20 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-30 07:35:09 | 2023-05-30 | 07:35:09 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-30 18:04:47 | 2023-05-30 | 18:04:47 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-30 07:35:14 | 2023-05-30 | 07:35:14 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-30 18:04:43 | 2023-05-30 | 18:04:43 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 07:27:15 | 2023-05-31 | 07:27:15 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 17:56:58 | 2023-05-31 | 17:56:58 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 17:57:02 | 2023-05-31 | 17:57:02 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 07:27:11 | 2023-05-31 | 07:27:11 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 07:27:19 | 2023-05-31 | 07:27:19 | Clock In |

This is my query:

```
WITH tanggal AS
(SELECT IDkaryawan, 
MIN(jam) AS minDate, 
MAX(jam) AS maxDate
FROM absen 
GROUP BY IDkaryawan)
DELETE FROM absen
  WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 FROM tanggal d 
        WHERE absen.IDkaryawan = d.IDkaryawan 
          AND absen.jam IN (d.minDate, d.maxDate));
```

This expected table:

| IDkaryawan | authDateTime | tanggal | jam | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-26 17:07:52 | 2023-05-26 | 17:07:52 | Clock Out |
| 1 | 2023-05-29 07:44:54 | 2023-05-29 | 07:44:54 | Clock In |
| 1 | 2023-05-29 17:05:56 | 2023-05-29 | 17:05:56 | Clock Out |
| 1 | 2023-05-30 07:45:37 | 2023-05-30 | 07:45:37 | Clock In |
| 1 | 2023-05-30 17:04:57 | 2023-05-30 | 17:04:57 | Clock Out |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 07:38:44 | 2023-05-31 | 07:38:44 | Clock In |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 17:08:26 | 2023-05-31 | 17:08:26 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-26 17:01:58 | 2023-05-26 | 17:01:58 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-29 17:01:03 | 2023-05-29 | 17:01:03 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-29 07:51:36 | 2023-05-29 | 07:51:36 | Clock In |
| 10 | 2023-05-30 07:53:48 | 2023-05-30 | 07:53:48 | Clock In |
| 10 | 2023-05-30 17:02:05 | 2023-05-30 | 17:02:05 | Clock Out |
| 10 | 2023-05-31 07:56:05 | 2023-05-31 | 07:56:05 | Clock In |
| 10 | 2023-05-31 17:00:20 | 2023-05-31 | 17:00:20 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-26 18:00:39 | 2023-05-26 | 18:00:39 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-29 07:24:41 | 2023-05-29 | 07:24:41 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-29 17:30:24 | 2023-05-29 | 17:30:24 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-30 07:35:09 | 2023-05-30 | 07:35:09 | Clock In |
| 12 | 2023-05-30 18:04:47 | 2023-05-30 | 18:04:47 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 17:57:02 | 2023-05-31 | 17:57:02 | Clock Out |
| 12 | 2023-05-31 07:27:11 | 2023-05-31 | 07:27:11 | Clock In |

I need the table just always check in and out time on each day for each employee, so no matter the min/max time, but the condition always selected check in/out time on each day for all employee.

Comment: Shouldn't you also GROUP BY `direction` to get min max per direction?

Comment: ive tried for adding GROUP BY direction,but AlMOST all data has removed and instead only the largest and smallest time remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `case` clause to determine which rows to keep :

```
WITH tanggal AS (
  SELECT IDkaryawan, tanggal, direction,
       CASE WHEN direction = 'Clock In' THEN MIN(jam) ELSE max(jam) END AS selected_jam
  FROM absen 
  GROUP BY IDkaryawan, tanggal, direction
)
DELETE FROM absen
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 FROM tanggal d
         WHERE
            absen.IDkaryawan = d.IDkaryawan AND
            absen.direction = d.direction AND
            absen.tanggal = d.tanggal AND
            absen.jam = d.selected_jam
      );
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T4AEVsOe)

Comment: youre crazy..btw thanks... would you shaere your paypal? or somethink? i want threat you starbucks or domino pizza if you want..btw thanks....

Comment: I'm glad I could help you ! I can't accept it, I'm here to help .. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You also must GROUP BY `tanggal` and `direction`:

```sql
WITH minmax AS
( SELECT IDkaryawan, tanggal, direction,
  MIN(jam) AS minDate,
  MAX(jam) AS maxDate
  FROM absen
  GROUP BY IDkaryawan, tanggal, direction
)
DELETE FROM absen
  WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 FROM minmax
         WHERE
            absen.IDkaryawan = minmax.IDkaryawan AND
            absen.tanggal = minmax.tanggal AND
            absen.direction = minmax.direction AND
            absen.jam IN (minmax.minDate, minmax.maxDate)
      );
```

Comment: The **tanggal** column is also need on `group by` and the condition, see demo here https://dbfiddle.uk/FsymwwqA

Comment: i think this query will make the data remove except min and max time ,also each days. so it remove almost all days

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added the column `tanggal` in the GROUP BY and the WHERE. And I also replaced the name `tanggal` for WITH expression by `minmax` to avoid confusion with the column name.

Comment: the result wasnt showing chek in/out for each days, because many days dissapear. it means that the query delete where id and min max time and check in/out,however the date doesnt include parameter

Comment: btw thanks for your help to answer my question.... hope you always luck.... i cant speak anything....once thanks.. :)